# MS SQL Query to find Name by joining over several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Project Table

```
Project
ShortDescription
Description
DB_ID
ProjektKMPoolStartDatum
ProjektKMPoolEndeDatum
```

ProjectManager

```
    DB_ID
ProjektID
KontaktID
```

Contact

```
Benutzeraccount
EMail
```

Imagine the following scenario:
in ProjectManager the owner of the project is listed (`KontaktID` is referring to Contact, `ProjektID` is referring to Project)

I need the query to find all Project.Project(so the real name not the ID) for KontaktID=somevalue

For some of you this might be easy, but I'm really awful in SQL so any help would be awesome :)

Sample Data:

ProjectManager

```
DB_ID   ProjektID   KontaktID
43         14          25
```

Project

```
Project    ShortDescription               Description                       DB_ID   ProjektKMPoolStartDatum ProjektKMPoolEndeDatum
ABC-Test   Fantasie-Projekt !!! Diese Projekt enhält nur Fantasie-Namen !!!   14         2015-02-27 07:34:42.000         NULL
```

Contact

```
DB_ID   Name    EMail
37     Ram Bo    xxx
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (Formatted text.)

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Comment: The question is how the tables are connected to each other. So is the `[Project Table]` joined with the `[ProjectManager]` over the `DB_ID` of each table or is it joined on `[ProjectManager].ProjektID = [Project Table].DB_ID` or `[ProjectManager].ProjektID = [Project Table].ProjektID`. So waht are your primary and foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL 101

```
select p.Project, c.Name as ContactName
from Contact c
inner join ProjectManager m  on (c.DB_ID = m.KontaktID)
inner join Project p on (m.ProjektID = p.DB_ID)
where c.DB_ID = @KontaktID;
```

You can replace @KontaktID by a hardcoded value, or declare the variable and set it before running the sql.

If you just need a list of the projects for a KontaktID then the Contact table doesn't even need to be in the SQL

```
select p.Project
from ProjectManager m
inner join Project p on (m.ProjektID = p.DB_ID)
where m.KontaktID = @KontaktID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Description FROM Project INNER JOIN DB_ID on Project.DB_ID = DB_ID.ProjektID  WHERE KontaktID=@KontaktID
```

assuming you have a variable `@KontaktID` or simply fill in the id there
(I adapted the join according to your sample data)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pr.Project 
FROM Project pr
JOIN ProjectManager pm on pr.DB_ID=pm.DB_ID
JOIN Contact c on pr.DB_ID=c.DB_ID
WHERE pm.KontaktID ='somevalue' --mention the filter condition
```